# Does this need to be transformed? If, yes, how?

Tags: data-transformation, histogram, qq-plot

My data is collecting deposition of particles from the atmosphere once a month for 11 months at two sites. I am testing to see if my two sites' data are normally distributed so I can determine what T-test to use to test for a difference between sites (thinking of Student t-test). But I need to make sure my two sites have normally distributed data. One site is normally distributed, and pretty obvious just by looking at a histogram. My issue is the other site: the Hatchery site...I am not sure if the data is normally distributed. I provide a QQ plot and a histogram for the Hatchery site. It's a small sample size (n=11) and I have one data point significantly higher than others. But it is hard for me to determine if it is normally distributed looking at the QQ plot. Should I transform this, and if so, what kind of transformation?
P.S. I provide one histogram that is log-transformed, which makes the data appear more normal...is log the way to go? When I used the Shapiro test on the log-transformed data, it gave a p-value of 0.124...thus saying it is normal. When I used the Shapiro test on the normal Hatchery data, the p-value was 0.003...

[image: Histogram][image: QQ Plot][image: Log-transform histogram]

Comment: "so I can determine what T-test to use to find a difference" - what difference? What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: Note that in general no data ever are perfectly normally distributed, but tests under normal assumption are often fine anyway due to the Central Limit Theorem. This however may well not apply to just 11 observations that look like yours. Any further course of action however depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Greetings Nick! I agree with Christian that more information is needed. It's not entirely clear what t-test you are interested in. Is this a repeated measures t-test (measuring "hatchery" multiple times within one group), an independent samples t-test (comparing two groups), or a one-sample t-test (comparing to a known population)? How many groups are being used? It will benefit everyone to have more information.

Comment: Previous comments are suitably cautious. In general, or rather in my experience, concentrations are best looked at on logarithmic scale so long as all reported values are positive.

Comment: Particle concentrations are clearly not normal (they're positive); if the test of normality fails to reject, it's simply a type II error. The more useful question is whether it matters to the properties of the test you wanted to do in the first place; for type I error that would relate to  population conditions when $H_0$ was true. I would encourage a careful consideration of Nick Cox's suggestion. (However, if you happen to have a detection threshold which features in the data, in some circumstances you might be best to consider the impact of such a threshold.)

Comment: Note that the concentrations here range from about 15 to 55 (units unstated so far as I can see, but that's not material). Over that range the logarithm plotted against the value shows only moderate curvature. But you may have other similar data and I still suggest working with logarithms. subject of course to caveats about zeros and limits of detection. That should make analyses slightly more appropriate, and not conversely.

Comment: @Nick If theory warrants it, these data might be expressed in terms of their *reciprocals.*  (That's a strong transformation, one I usually hesitate to apply without more justification than the univariate distribution of data alone.) A standard midletter summary plot (a la Tukey) provides a good *univariate* method to find a Box-Cox parameter-- but we have to respect all the cautions already stated about purpose, context, nature of the model, and so on.

Comment: @whuber Indeed, reciprocals would make more of a difference.  I usually want to think that a reciprocal makes sense in terms of units and dimensions and I think there is a good case here.